# Value of state within React context not updating when used in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-context

I'm trying to use context in conjunction with state to do role-based routing with React router. Upon clicking sign in, the user data is fetched from the backend API and set as state within the context provider.

The issue is that when I then attempt to use that state in my authorization component that I wrap around my route, the state isn't updated (I presume). What am I missing here?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-mopsa-yffzvk?file=/src/App.js)

The context:

```
const CurrentUserContext = createContext({});

export const CurrentUserProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null)
    const [currentUserRole, setCurrentUserRole] = useState(null)
    const requestOption = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        }
    }
    const fetchCurrentUser = () => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users-current/', requestOption)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('called')
                setCurrentUser(data['user'])
                setCurrentUserRole(data['role'])
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    return (
        <CurrentUserContext.Provider value={{
            setCurrentUser,
            setCurrentUserRole,
            currentUser,
            currentUserRole,
            fetchCurrentUser
        }}>
            {children}
        </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
    )
}


export const useAuth = () => useContext(CurrentUserContext)
```

The sign in component where I run fetchCurrentUser on sign in to set the state etc:

```
export default function SignIn() {
    
    const { fetchCurrentUser } = useAuth()
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
        const credentials = btoa(`${data.get('username')}:${data.get('password')}`);

        const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Authorization": `Basic ${credentials}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({})

        }
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', data['token'])
                localStorage.setItem('role', data['role'])
            })
            .then(fetchCurrentUser())
            .catch(error => console.log(error))

    }
```

The component where I'm trying to access the currentUser state:

```
import { useLocation, Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router";
import { useAuth } from "./CurrentUserContext"

const RequireAuth = () => {

    const { currentUser } = useAuth()
    const location = useLocation()

    return (
        currentUser
        ? <Outlet />
        : <Navigate
                to="/"
                state={{ from: location }}
                replace
            />
    )
}

export default RequireAuth;
```

And finally my routes:

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <CurrentUserProvider>
        <DialogProvider>
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route element={<RequireAuth/>}>
                        <Route path="roles" element={<DashboardContent role={true}/>}/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/" element={<SignIn/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </DialogProvider>
        </CurrentUserProvider>
```

If I navigate to roles after signing in I'm just redirected to the sign in page again since currentUser is null.

Comment: `.then(fetchCurrentUser())` Not sure if this is the whole problem, but this should be `.then(fetchCurrentUser)` or `.then(() => fetchCurrentUser())`. You're currently calling fetchCurrentUser *immediately*, not after the login completes.

Comment: I've tried that too, no dice unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure of your authentication response value? What is the value of `data['user']` upon successful response? Is there an error occurring?

Comment: The response value is fine as far as I can tell. If I console log it it's the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a stale enclosure over the `requestOption` object in the `CurrentUser` component. The `SignIn` component only updates the localStorage in the `handleSubmit` handler before calling `fetchCurrentUser` which uses the closed over `requestOption` object that hasn't pulled in the updated `token` value from localStorage.

Move the options into the `fetchCurrentUser` callback so they are computed on-demand from the *current* localStorage value.

```
export const CurrentUserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [currentUserRole, setCurrentUserRole] = useState(null);
    
  const fetchCurrentUser = () => {
    const requestOption = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      }
    };

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users-current/', requestOption)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log('called');
        setCurrentUser(data.user);
        setCurrentUserRole(data.role);
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  };

  return (
    <CurrentUserContext.Provider
      value={{
        setCurrentUser,
        setCurrentUserRole,
        currentUser,
        currentUserRole,
        fetchCurrentUser
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

...

```
export default function SignIn() {
  const { fetchCurrentUser } = useAuth();

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    const credentials = btoa(`${data.get('username')}:${data.get('password')}`);

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Basic ${credentials}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({})
    };

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/', requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', data['token'])
        localStorage.setItem('role', data['role'])
      })
      .then(fetchCurrentUser) // <-- don't immediately invoke!
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

  ...
```

Comment: Didn't fix it unfortunately. The call to /api/users-current works both ways, if I console log the data before setting the state it's the correct value.

Comment: @user17817249 Don't immediately invoke `fetchCurrentUser`. At this point we may just need a reproducible code example. Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: Would it be alright to use mock data in place of the results from the API calls in the codesandbox? Not sure how I'd add that to a sandbox since the API is local on my PC.

Comment: @user17817249 Yes, please... mock the API responses.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-mopsa-yffzvk?file=/src/App.js

Here's the sandbox

Comment: @user17817249 Have you pushed all the code to the sandbox and saved it? I see a bunch of empty files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243163/discussion-between-user17817249-and-drew-reese).

Comment: @user17817249 Sorry for taking so long to revisit this conversation. After copying the context code from the pastebin into your sandbox, and after fixing the mock API response data accesses, I was able to successfully "authenticate" and navigate to the `"/roles"` component. https://codesandbox.io/s/value-of-state-within-react-context-not-updating-when-used-in-another-component-jlhr76

Comment: No problem, thanks for checking it. I temporarily solved it by using local storage instead of state but I will check the sandbox you provided.

Comment: @user17817249 Ok. And again, sorry for the extreme delay.

Comment: Hi again, I've implemented the changes and it works now but there is another issue. If I try to login, the same problem as before persists where the state remains the default value. But if I try to login again immediately after, the state changes and everything works as intended. Do you have any ideas as to why this would be? I have checked on the backend and the first login is successful and a token is successfully generated.

Comment: @user17817249 Nothing immediate comes to mind. This seems like one of those instances where a running example with exact reproduction steps is really helpful.